# boxplot showmeans ignored in seaborn (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a boxplot with seaborn with this line of code:

`plot = sns.boxplot(x='Fecha', y='spread', data=merge, showfliers=False, showmeans=True, order=fechas)`

but the showmeans property is ignored in the plot. So, I obtain this chart:

[image]

Why is this happening? and how can I fix that? Thanks

I'm using:
python 3.9.5
seaborn 0.11.1

Comment: Did you try setting explicit properties for the mean, e.g. `sns.boxplot(...., meanprops={'color':'red'})`?

Comment: Yes, and I tried to make it bigger, but nothing works

Comment: When I compute the means those means were only infinite numbers, so I think this problem is not related with seaborn

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it doesn't work in your case, but if I had to do it manually, I would do this:

```py
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, showfliers=False, color='C0')
means = tips.groupby('day')['total_bill'].mean()
ax.plot(range(len(means)), means, color='red', marker='s', linewidth=0)
```

[image: seaborn boxplot]

Only makes sure that x-axis match in two plots.

Comment: I try your solution and I notice that the array 'means' have only infinite numbers. I think the problem is not related with seaborn

Comment: @mxmlnlrcn So, you might filter out the invalid values from your data? Note that `showmeans` is not handled by seaborn, but passed to matplotlib.

Comment: That's exactly what fixed my chart. Thank you